# How to change file name in c#?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with the file name returns from the file dialog box.
I need to change only the file name but not its path.
I want something like this...

```
string name_to_change="abc";
string filenameAtClient = this.saveFileDialog.FileName;
filenameAtClient=name_to_change;
```

Comment: You mean to change the name of the file in file system or in your `filenameAtClient` variable?

Comment: in my filenameAtClient variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string name_to_change = "abc";
string filenameAtClient = this.saveFileDialog.FileName;
filenameAtClient = filenameAtClient.Replace(Path.GetFileName(filenameAtClient), name_to_change);
```

OR without the file extension:

```
string name_to_change = "abc";
string filenameAtClient = this.saveFileDialog.FileName;
filenameAtClient = filenameAtClient.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filenameAtClient), name_to_change);
```

Comment: thanks for your response but it is not returning the extension

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to change the filename with extension, the filename without extension or just the extension?

Comment: you were right .. I have done it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to check MSDN, for example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.renamefile(v=vs.110).aspx